# Continue a dialog with silence as an input

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I have written a dialog which should continue if there is no input from the user, ie, after a prompt, a user does not input anything. For checking inactivity, I am using a back-channel mechanism to propagate an event to the Bot 'n' seconds, to continue with the next step in the dialog. I am intercepting this event in both OnContinueDialogAsync() as well as OnEventActivityAsync(), but am not able to get the bot to continue with the conversation. My code in OnContinueDialogAsync() is as follows:

```
if (innerDc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event)
{
      if (innerDc.ActiveDialog != null && innerDc.ActiveDialog.Id.Equals("DailyBriefDialog", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
                    innerDc.Context.Activity.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
                    //innerDc.Context.Activity.Text = "continue";
      }
      await _stateAccessor.GetAsync(innerDc.Context,()=> new SkillState());
            return await base.OnContinueDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
}
```

My OnEventActivityAsync() is as follows:

```
protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var ev = innerDc.Context.Activity.AsEventActivity();
        var value = ev.Value?.ToString();
    switch (ev.Name)
        {
            case TokenEvents.TokenResponseEventName:
                    {
                        // Forward the token response activity to the dialog waiting on the stack.
                        await innerDc.ContinueDialogAsync();
                        break;
                    }
                case StateProperties.Inactive:
                    {
                        if (innerDc.ActiveDialog != null && innerDc.ActiveDialog.Id.Equals("DailyBriefDialog", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                            await innerDc.ContinueDialogAsync();
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync(new Activity(type: ActivityTypes.Trace, text: $"Unknown Event '{ev.Name ?? "undefined"}' was received but not processed."));
                        break;
                    }
         }
}
```

This setup, re-runs the previous step of the dialog multiple times. However, I would like to proceed to the next step of the Dialog.

Comment: Not sure if it will work here, or what the C# syntax is, but have you tried using `next()` instead of `continueDialog()`? I'm not sure if innerDc is the same as the context object in your waterfall dialog.

Comment: As pointed out by billoverton, the waterfall step should know when it is a timeout event, and call next()